# Jqgrid add dialog box how to change width and height of field?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i'm using jqgrid asp.net component .how can i change a filed width  and height (text box or combo) in add and edit dialog boxes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the last im found it

1 you need to specify edittype attribute

2 after that specify editfiled attributes tag

**for text area**

```
 <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" Editable="true" EditType="TextArea">
                        <Formatter>
                            <trirand:CustomFormatter FormatFunction="formatRating" UnFormatFunction="unformatRating" />
                        </Formatter>
                        <EditFieldAttributes>
                            <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="cols" Value="80" />
                            <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="rows" Value="6" />
                        </EditFieldAttributes>
                    </trirand:JQGridColumn>
```

> **for text box**

```
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Design" HeaderText="Design" Editable="true" EditDialogFieldSuffix=" (MAX - 10)">
                        <Formatter>
                            <trirand:CustomFormatter FormatFunction="formatRating" UnFormatFunction="unformatRating" />
                        </Formatter>
                        <EditFieldAttributes>
                            <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="2" />
                        </EditFieldAttributes>
                    </trirand:JQGridColumn>
```

[image]